# tcolorbox causes compilation error in VSCode

Tags: tcolorbox, vscode, latex-workshop

I started getting compilation errors after I added `tcolorbox` to my project. I use VSCode and the Latex Workshop extension. What is strange is that the build fails when running normally, but when I close and reopen VSCode the PDF is rendered properly.

Compiler log:

```
{/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/dejavu/dejavumono_t1-type1.enc}{/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/ly1/texnansi.enc}</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Bold.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/bitstrea/charter/bchb8a.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/bitstrea/charter/bchr8a.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/bitstrea/charter/bchri8a.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi12.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/mathdesign/mdbch/md-chr7t.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/mathdesign/mdbch/md-chr7v.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/mathdesign/mdbch/md-chr7y.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/mathdesign/mdbch/md-chr8t.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/mathdesign/mdbch/md-chri7m.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/mathdesign/mdbch/md-chrma.pfb>
Output written on /home/myname/project/project-thesis/thesis.pdf (49 pages, 3163920 bytes).
SyncTeX written on /home/myname/project/project-thesis/thesis.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on /home/myname/project/project-thesis/thesis.log.
'thesis.fls' and '/home/myname/project/project-thesis/thesis.fls' are identical (not copied) at /usr/bin/latexmk line 6657.
Latexmk: Non-existent bbl file 'thesis.bbl'
 No file thesis.bbl.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'thesis.pdf'
Latexmk: ===For rule 'pdflatex', actual output 'thesis.pdf'
       ======appears not to match expected output '/home/myname/project/project-thesis/thesis.pdf'
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 256
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs of latex/pdflatex.
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
```

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SX! I assume that your bibliography fails according to the log. It renders partially correct because the first compilation with `pdflatex` has been finished. (Normal LaTeXmk with `pdflatex` backend consists of `pdflatex`->`bibtex/biber`->`pdflatex`*2)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that is the issue. The problem only started occurring after I added the tcolorbox package. Renders completely fine in Overleaf btw.